# Xcode Auto Complete Code snippet , replace shortcut Text

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

As you can see, I have added a custom code snippet and a shortcut.
Problem is that my snippet is `//ABC` and my snippet shortcut is `//`

Now when i select the snippet from the autocomplete feature in Xcode, it does NOT replace the shortcut text, and it becomes this

```
`////ABC`
```

Now in other in build classes/functions in Xcode, autocomplete works in a different way. When we write a wrong spelling and select the autocomplete from Xcode, it replaces the shortcut text. I want to know how to apply this in Custom snippets. I have gone through the edit portion of the snippet but replacing shortcut text is not found. How is this possible? if it is

I am using XCode 8.3, and my OS is macOSSierra.

Comment: symbols starting with / are not suggested for autocomplete code snippet shortcut as // is used for commenting purpose..Try other symbols except starting with /

Comment: Changed it to abc, but its still overlapping as suggested before. Reinstalling Xcode and hopefully it wont happen as I am finding some other issues with my Xcode as well.